# Не работает слайдер на js

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер!

Не получается создать слайдер, не могу понять в чем дело. По нажатию на стрелку current меняется, однако слайд не меняется ( 9 строка ).

Буду рад помощи.

```js
let sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('sliders');
arrowLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('arrowleft'),
  arrowRight = document.getElementsByClassName('arrowright'),
  current = 0;

function startSlide() {
  hideSlide();
  arrow();
  sliders[current].style.display = 'block';
}

function hideSlide() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
    sliders[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
}

function arrow() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrowRight.length; i++) {
    arrowRight[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      return current++
    })
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arrowLeft.length; i++) {
    arrowLeft[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      return current--
    })
  }
}
startSlide();

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(current)
}, 1000)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sliders {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.sliders1 {
  background-image: url('../img/1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}

.sliders2 {
  background-image: url('../img/2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliders3 {
  background-image: url('../img/3.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.arrowleft {
  margin-left: 13%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrowright {
  margin-right: 13%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sliders1 {
  background-image: url('../img/1.jpg');
}

.sliders2 {
  background-image: url('../img/2.jpg')
}

.sliders3 {
  background-image: url('../img/3.jpg')
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Проект15</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="sliders">
      <div class="sliders1">
        <div class="arrowleft">
          <img src="img/left-arrow.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="arrowright">
          <img src="img/right-arrow.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliders">
      <div class="sliders2">
        <div class="arrowleft">
          <img src="img/left-arrow.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="arrowright">
          <img src="img/right-arrow.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliders">
      <div class="sliders3">
        <div class="arrowleft">
          <img src="img/left-arrow.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="arrowright">
          <img src="img/right-arrow.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Ссылка: [codepen](https://codepen.io/viktorMeladze/pen/VXxmwj)

Comment: Ссылка не работает?

Comment: Сам клик на стрелку работает и меняет счетчик, счетчик меняется, а слайд, к которому current привязан, не меняется

Comment: Вы на клик повесили только переключение счетчика. Переключение слайдов на клике нет